# Bootstrap Argument for elliptic equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, bootstrap-sampling

I am dealing with the following partial differential equation.

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
u_t & = \nabla \cdot \left(\frac{\nabla u}{1+w^2}\right) & \text{ in } Q_T; \\
-\epsilon \Delta w & = \bigl|\nabla f\bigl|^2 - w & \text{ in } Q_T; \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}(x,t) & =0 & \text{ on } \partial \Omega \times (0, T); \\
w(x,t) & =0 & \text{ on } \partial \Omega \times (0, T); \\
u(x,0) & =u_0(x) & \text{ in } \Omega \
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
with $\Omega = \{x \in R^2 | ||x||_2<1\}$ and $Q_T=\Omega \times (0,T)$.
I have $f \in H^2(\Omega)$ and therefore there exist a weak solution $w \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and we can even proof that $w \in H^3(\Omega)$.

Moreover, we obtain the following inequality by Sobolev embedding theorems.
$$||w||_{C^1(\bar{\Omega})}\leq C(\varepsilon)||f||_{H^3(\Omega)}$$ for all $t \in (0,T_0)$.
I can therefore proof that there exist a weak solution of the partial differential equation in $L^2(H^1(\Omega);(0,T_0))$.
So we have $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ in the space an $u \in L^2(0,T_0)$ in time.

Now i need for further calculations that $u \in H^3(\Omega)$.
Is it possible that i get this higher regularity by a bootstrapping argument?
And if this is the case, how exactly does it work?
I just got the hint and read through some papers on bootstrapping but didn't really figure it out.

Comment: The most low-effort approach is to differentiate the parabolic equation and apply the standard energy estimate to the equation for the derivative. When you do this, you get a "good" part when the derivatives hit $u$, and some "bad" parts when the derivatives hit $w$. For the latter, you would use whatever estimates you have available for $w$ already, like the $C^1$ estimate you mention (this is enough to take one derivative, getting $u \in H^2$), and after that presumably Sobolev estimates. I'll note it's not clear why $f \in H^2$ implies $w \in H^3$, I'd expect $w \in W^{3, 1}$ or a bit less.

Comment: 1. Thanks for the answer. I did this in space dimension 1. That has worked. But now I am space dimension 2 and there I have problems to transfer it, because I would have to take now the gradient but so then also land in a vector field. Or how would I then derive this with respect to x?

2. Since $f \in H^2$ i have $|\nabla f|^2 \in H^1$ and since i have $\partial \Omega \in C^2$ i have $w \in H^3$ if we consider the second equation and the elliptic regularization theory

Comment: You do it for each partial derivative separately (and then repeatedly for each entry in the Hessian, etc, if you need to go higher). $f \in H^2$ implies $|\nabla f|\in H^1$, so $|\nabla f|^2 \in W^{1, 1}$.

Comment: Oh that's right. Thank you for the comment. However, I need $w \in H^3$ and accordingly choose my $f$ to fit. According to this, I would need to choose $f \in W^{2,4}$? Then $|\nabla f| $would be $\in W^{1,4}$ and $|\nabla f |^2 \in H^1$ right?

Comment: I guess since you are in 2D you can actually do better than what I wrote: e.g. $f \in H^2$ implies $|\nabla f| \in L^q$ for any $q < \infty$ by embedding, and so $(|\nabla f|^2)_e = 2 \nabla f \cdot \nabla f_e$ is in $L^p$ for any $p < 2$ by Holder; $H^1$ is then borderline. $f \in W^{2, 2 + \delta}$ for any $\delta > 0$ is enough.

Comment: For the evolution problem on $u$: it is an abstract ODE associated to an unbounded operator. Apply the Hille Yosida theory in an Hilbertian framework: the operator is self adjoint and has compact resolvant hence diagonalizable is a Hilbert basis. The spectrum is bounded above so it’s a generator (this shows the problem is well posed in the mild sens for any $u_0 \in L^2$). When you express the solution $u$ taking advantage of the diagonal structure, you can show the series concerges normally in $H^3$ bounding above the $H^3$ norm of these eigenfunctions.